# What is the best way to split a variable length string into variables in Python?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string of integers separated by commas of variable length. What is the best way to split the string and store the integers into variables?

Currently, I have the following.

```
input = sys.argv[1]
mylist = [int(x) for x in input.split(',')]
if len(mylist) == 2: a, b = mylist
else: a, b, c = mylist
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: The split part looks pretty good, why bother putting it into separate variables? Is it only going to be 2 or 3?

Comment: How are you going to access `c` if you (depending on the input) don't create it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add sentinels, then limit the list to 3 elements:

```
a, b, c = (mylist + [None] * 3)[:3]
```

Now a, b and c are at the very least set to None, and if the number of items is more than three only the first three values are used.

Demo:

```
>>> mylist = [1, 2]
>>> a, b, c = (mylist + [None] * 3)[:3]
>>> print a, b, c
1 2 None
>>> mylist = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a, b, c = (mylist + [None] * 3)[:3]
>>> print a, b, c
1 2 3
```

If you need at least 2 elements, use fewer None values and catch ValueError:

```
try:
    a, b, c = (mylist + [None])[:3]
except ValueError:
    print "You mast specify at least 2 values"
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: @larsmans: Hey, you are not the only one with all the tricks. :-P I may admit to having been reminded though...

Comment: Actually, adding a single `None` may be better in this case, since the list must have at least two elements. But you already have my +1.

Comment: @larsmans: This is more generic; the OP code indeed checks for 2 or 3, but perhaps he wanted 0 or 1 too. :-)

Comment: @idealistikz: Please, could you make that a *new* question instead of changing this one after accepting it? That's a pretty substantive change in the problem requirements, in my opinion.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11314395/whats-the-best-way-to-parse-values-from-a-variable-length-string

Answer (score 1):

Just an addendum to Martjin. Turned it into a function to show why you might use it. You can do dynamic sentinels using

```
def store(mylist,expsiz = 10, dflt = None):
    return mylist + [dflt]*(expsiz-len(mylist))

>>> mylist = [1,2,5]
>>> fixedlen = store(mylist)
>>> print fixedlen
[1,2,5,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]
```