# What's the best way to parse values from a variable length string?

Tags: python

Suppose I have a string of integers separated by commas of variable length. What is the best way to split the string and update variables with values if they exist?

Currently, I have the following.

```
a, b, c = 10, 10, 1    #default values
mylist = [int(x) for x in input.split(',')]
if len(mylist) == 2: a, b = mylist
else: a, b, c = mylist
```

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Before anyone closes this as a dupe; note that the OP now wants to use default values.

Comment: This is a follow-up to [What is the best way to split a variable length string into variables in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313256/what-is-the-best-way-to-split-a-variable-length-string-into-variables-in-python)

Comment: @idealistikz: For what you are asking, the code is efficient enough IMO. I can't think of a way to improve the speed of what you're doing. Could you provided a context or some more code perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a, b, c = 10, 10, 1    #default values
mylist = [int(x) for x in input.split(',')]
a, b, c = mylist + [a, b, c][len(mylist):]
```

I think the reason this is ugly is that it's non-Pythonic to treat local variables in aggregate; instance members would be more appropriate.

Comment: you need `if x` in the listcomp for an empty input.

Comment: @astynax: raising an exception if `len(mylist)>3` is a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a helper function:

```
def f(a=10, b=10, c=1):
    return a, b, c

a, b, c = f(*map(int, input.split()))
```

This won't be faster – it's just a different way to do it that just crossed my mind.

Answer (score 1):

```
defaults=[10,10,1]
mylist=[int(x) for x in ipt.split(',')]
defaults[:len(mylist)]=mylist
a,b,c=defaults
```

This changes `defaults` though...  You to avoid that, something like this would work:

```
defaults=[10,10,1]
mylist=[int(x) for x in ipt.split(',')]
temp_defaults=defaults[:]
temp_defaults[:len(mylist)]=mylist
a,b,c=temp_defaults
```

Also, be careful using `input` as a variable name.  It's the name of a python built-in so you're removing your easy access to that function.

Comment: Is this more efficient than the original method?

Comment: @idealistikz -- More efficient in what way?  computation speed?  I have no idea.  You could time it with `timeit`.

Answer (score 1):

Use slicing to combine the user input with the list of default arguments:

```
>>> defaults = [10, 10, 1]
>>> user_input = '15 20'
>>> user_ints = map(int, user_input.split())
>>> combined = user_ints + defaults[len(user_ints):]
>>> a, b, c = combined
```

Answer (score 0):

`izip_longest` allows to take the length of the default values if longer:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> inp = '3, 56'
>>> a, b, c = [i if i else j for i, j in izip_longest([int(x) for x in inp.split(',')], (10, 10, 1))]
>>> a, b, c
(3, 56, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a, b, c = (map(int, user_input.split(',')) + [20,20,10])[:3]
```

or

```
def parse(user_input, *args):
    return (map(int, user_input.split(',')) + list(args))[:len(args)]

>>> a, b, c = parse('1,2', 20, 20, 10)
>>> a, b, c
(1, 2, 20)
>>> a, b, c, d = parse('1,2,3,4,5', 0, 0, 0, 0)
>>> a, b, c, d
(1, 2, 3, 4)
```